# Emscripten compilation error with glew

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glew, emscripten

I am compiling my opengl program with:

```
emcc -std=c++11 -I .\GL\ .\src\main.cpp -s USE_GLFW=3 -o glCore.js
```

and everything works ok, but when I add the attribute `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_initGL']"` I get unresolved symbol on all glew commands in that function, for example `__glewBindBuffer`.

If I add the flag `-s LINKABLE=1` it compiles again. The `LINKABLE` flag is not recommended so I wonder if there are any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, I should not include my own glew.h file, it should be the one from emscripten.

So when I removed `-I .\GL\` it worked